# simplefacebook SSO fallback won't do anythin

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-sdk-3.0, android-simple-facebook

I have tried the Wrapper with facebook installed and everything worked fine: SSO, then publish via custom dialog and everything worked fine.

Then i wanted to do the same on a machine without the facebook app installed, but after the login dialog nothing happened.

Basically, this is the code. I followed basically the code of the sample, so the most of the code should be "familiar":

Fragment fields:

```
    private SimpleFacebook mSimpleFacebook;     
    private OnLoginListener mOnLoginListener = new OnLoginListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onThinking()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            toast("Thinking");
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(Throwable throwable)
        {
            toast("Exception: " + throwable.getMessage());
            Log.e(TAG, "Bad thing happened", throwable);            
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(String reason)
        {
            toast(reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLogin()
        {
            publishFeed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNotAcceptingPermissions(Type type)
        {
            toast("Permission not accepted");   
        }

    };

    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
```

Fragment onCreate:

```
        Permission[] permissions = new Permission[]
                {
                Permission.USER_PHOTOS,
                Permission.EMAIL,
                Permission.PUBLISH_ACTION
                };

        SimpleFacebookConfiguration configuration = new SimpleFacebookConfiguration.Builder()
        .setAppId(AppConstants.FB_APPID)
                    .setNamespace(AppConstants.FB_APP_NAMESPACE)
                    .setPermissions(permissions)
                    .build();

        SimpleFacebook.setConfiguration(configuration);
```

Fragment onResume as in Sample

Button in Fragment view:

```
mSimpleFacebook.login(mOnLoginListener);
```

publishFeed. The Last static function in Utils generates the Feed and the AlertDialog.

```
        private void publishFeed()
        {
            // listener for publishing action
            OnPublishListener onPublishListener = new OnPublishListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onFail(String reason)
                {
                    hideDialog();
                    // insure that you are logged in before publishing
                    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to publish");
//                  toast("Failed to publish");
                }

                @Override
                public void onException(Throwable throwable)
                {
                    hideDialog();
                    Log.e(TAG, "Bad thing happened", throwable);
//                  toast("Bad thing happened");
                }

                @Override
                public void onThinking()
                {
                    // show progress bar or something to the user while publishing
                    showDialog();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(String postId)
                {
                    hideDialog();
                    ActionType type = ActionType.FBPOST;
                    if(MQData.getInstance().checkEventConstraint(mEvent, getActivity().getApplicationContext()))
                    {
                        type = ActionType.FBPOSTEVENT;
                    }
                    Points.addPoints(type, mEvent.getEvent_id(), getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    mActivity.onActionBarChanged(false);
                }
            };

            // feed builder
//          Feed feed = new Feed.Builder()
//              .setMessage("Clone it out...")
//              .setName("Simple Facebook SDK for Android")
//              .setCaption("Code less, do the same.")
//              .setDescription("The Simple Facebook library project makes the life much easier by coding less code for being able to login, publish feeds and open graph stories, invite friends and more.")
//              .setPicture("https://raw.github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/master/Refs/android_facebook_sdk_logo.png")
//              .setLink("https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook")
//              .addAction("Like us on Facebook", "https://www.facebook.com/MuseumsQuartierWien")
//              .build();
//          
//          mSimpleFacebook.publish(feed, true, onPublishListener);

            Utils.createFBPostBuilder(mEvent, getActivity(), mSimpleFacebook, onPublishListener).create().show();
        }
```

Is there anything wrong? Do i have to make special configurations in my Facebook App or is it just an error in the Android code?

Thanks in advance,

Lukas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for my problem.

I thought it was sufficient to add onActivityResult in the Fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    mSimpleFacebook.onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ...
}
```

but i also had to add this in the activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    SimpleFacebook.getInstance(this).onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```